# How can I sync my new iPad on Ubuntu?

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, unix

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and I would like to add some songs and videos.

Comment: This should be on the Ubuntu stack exchange IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this thread out
https://askubuntu.com/questions/994/can-i-sync-with-my-iphone-4-and-ipad

otherwise you might ask directly on askubuntu. 
You can log in on askubuntu using your stackexchange credentials

Comment: thanks, I asked the question on askubuntu (I can sync music but I do not see them on my iPad)